# Hiding the follow suggestion list one by one after clicking

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, hide

I want the follow person suggestions be hidden after the user clicks on them on my django application. How to do this with jquery? My code also carries ajax request.

```
    $(function () {
    $('.follow_btn').on('click', function () {
        var clicked_user = $(this);
        var user_id = $(this).data('user_id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url "follow" %}',
            type: 'get',
            data: {id: user_id}
        }).done(function (data) {
            clicked_user.next('small').text('OK').css('color', 'green');
        }).fail(function (err) {
            alert(err);
        });
    });
});
```

May be my code isn't that perfect. I've tried several options but nothing changes.

Comment: you can use $(this).hide() as well;Check this normally iam showing this with static html and jquery  https://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/r8t1z403/

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but it's now working. Do you know how to do this without a page refresh. There is always a gap before I do a refresh. Thanks a lot.

Comment: without seeing what actually you are doing cannot say

Comment: somehow I managed to to that. Thanks for the help